# In OSX running oh-my-zsh creating alias for show and hide files with killall Finder wont work

Tags: macos, bash, alias, zsh, hidden-files

Im attempting to create an alias for the show and hide of hidden files. I would really like to chain the rewrite with the finder kill into a single alias. I've created the 'aliases.zsh' file in the 'ZSH_CUSTOM' directory (which i'm only assuming is the correct method and placement, please correct me if I am wrong). It seems that the rewrite segment of the alias is functioning properly but the 'killall Finder' command won't execute. I'm new to using aliases and to customizing zsh functionality but am pretty capable of general shell operation.

Im running:
-mavericks 10.9.5
-oh-my-zsh
-iTerm 2

I've tried:
`alias showon='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES && killall Finder'
alias showoff='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO && killall Finder'`
*also tried the exact syntax above using double quotes*

Also tried:
`alias showon='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder'
alias showoff='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder'`
*I found this and tried it assuming used the semi-colon to separate the commands might work.*

Update:
Tried adding a kill alias alone:
`alias kf="killall Finder"`
*This also does not function. Perhaps it isn't the syntax I'm using that is the problem… again Im at a loss.*

Update:
Running:`killall -v Finder`
Outputs:`kill -TERM 3125`
*successfully relaunches finder*

In ~/.zshrc:
I created: alias jkl="killall Finder"
Running:`jkl`
Outputs:`zsh: command not found: jkl`

I have had no success with efforts thus far. My error maybe glaring to someone versed in this sort of thing, or if anyone just has an idea, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this post, while having the same problem, and here's what worked for me.

Add the following two lines to your `.zshrc` file, and don't forget to save and restart iterm2. I thought mine was bombing out and realized I hadn't restarted the shell yet, then it worked ;).

```sh
alias showFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'
alias hideFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't need to restart terminal. Just hit this command `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Killing the finder doesn't work anymore in Mavericks. The problem is that Mavericks caches user preferences system-wide, and (if I've got this right) if you kill Finder it will restore them to their previous state. See this link for details and a sort of work-around:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5483892

Comment: Is that through chained aliases specifically? If I kill finder direct from the command line, it works as expected.

Comment: Hm, I didn't know that, and I don't have Mavericks. Apple claims it shouldn't. Try inserting a `sleep 1` (or bigger) before the `killall`, maybe you just need enough time for the preference change to get committed before killing the Finder.

Comment: I just added an update about the fact that even an exclusive alias (dedicated to the finder kill alone) doesn't work. I do appreciate the ideas, and if you have another, I'm all ears.

Comment: Using a separate alias should NOT be any different from typing it on the command line. Are you 100% sure it does work when you type it by hand? Try also `killall -v Finder`, which tell you what it'll do.

Comment: I posted the update to your idea. When run directly, killall Finder appears to just kill the associated process as expected. After creating `alias jkl="killall Finder"` (directly in ~/.zshrc) it tells me the command isn't found.

Comment: Seriously? It's telling you your _alias_ isn't found. Look at your error message. You need `. ~/.zshrc`, or to open a new shell, for the alias to take effect.

Comment: Perhaps it was just as simple as restarting iTerm. What threw me off was that the rewrite was working without a restart or new shell while the kill wasn't. I did move the complete alias to ~/.zshrc and it is functioning now. At the risk of asking a different question here, does it matter if aliases are placed in ~/.zshrc vs ZSH_CUSTOM? There is a comment in zshrc that says user aliases should be placed in ZSH_CUSTOM.

Comment: I don't use zsh, but generally this is a matter of taste. If the aliases are present when you start the shell, they are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a zsh function so you don't have to remember two aliases (even though they're quite simple in this case). Create `~/.config/zsh/functions` if it doesn't exist and add the following:

```
function toggle_hf
{
  current=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles);
  if [[ $current == "NO" ]] then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder;
    echo "Showing hidden files";
  else
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder;
    echo "Hiding hidden files";
  fi
}
```

then `source ~/.config/zsh/functions` and you will be able to run `toggle_hf` to toggle hidden file visibility on/off.